# Unit tests for local Swift packages don't show inline results in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, swift-package-manager

I've recently been refactoring a project to use local swift packages for better modularisation. I've shifted the relevant unit tests into the packages, and added the individual package tests to the overall test plan, and tests run fine from the Xcode Test Navigator pane.

However, from the test .swift files themselves, it's not possible to run individual tests from the usual diamond-shaped test button found next to each `func testXYZ()`, and more importantly, none of the test failures show up inline any more (I have to scroll through the test logs instead). I know these test files are no longer target members of a unit test target, but they **are** mentioned as tests in each `Package` file's `testTarget`, and Xcode knows to test them when I hit command-U.

If I open the package itself in Xcode, rather than attached to an Xcode project, I can run and check the tests in the usual way. But this is a bit jarring as I have to close the main project first, and I will have up to 10 local packages in my project, so it's not a great work flow.

**Has anybody encountered this and found a way to improve the workflow?**

Comment: I have no problem running individual tests in a local package from within my main App Xcode project and any errors can be seen inlined. Personally I like that I can have my code divided into different local packages based on functionality and that it keeps my architecture clean with much clearer dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to say it, but a week later I'm suddenly just seeing those unit tests appear and function inline after all. I don't know what the concrete step was that fixed the issue - could've just been restarting my Mac for all I know. If like me you're struggling for a fix, it's likely nothing to do with any Xcode or `Package` file settings, and more just a caching error somewhere.

Comment: I have the same issue, however I can't see in my units tests this triangle button to start tests which are in local Swift package. I tried various targets (project as well as defined in the swift package as test target) and nothing.

But I discovered workaround. From test navigator I can see my tests and it is possible to run these tests from here.